# Can I simplify the implementation of listeners in Kotlin or Java?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

```
binding.seekbarConstrast.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object :
            SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
            override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean){}

            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {}

            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
                mainViewModel.adjustConstrast(
                    ProcessUtils.seek2param(
                        seekBar!!.max, 0f, 4f, seekBar.progress
                    )
                )
            }
        })
```

This code is in Android,I hate below code,too many seekbars make meaningless code extremely long,
Can I use Kotlin or Java to simplify the implementation of listeners?Like Android animation adapter,only implementation what I want use.Thank you.

```
override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean){}
override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {}
```

Comment: Create you custom listener as per your requirement

Comment: Thank you.I was so stupid that I never thought of this way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create your own custom listener as per your requirement

```
abstract class OnSeekBarSimpleChangeListener : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
    override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
        // Nothing
    }

    override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
        // Nothing
    }

}
```

And then use

```
binding.seekbarConstrast.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : OnSeekBarSimpleChangeListener() {

    override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
        mainViewModel.adjustConstrast(
            ProcessUtils.seek2param(
                seekBar!!.max, 0f, 4f, seekBar.progress
            )
        )
    }
})
```